# How to make a file to run with Task Manager to close a program at a certain time each day?

Tags: batch-file

I seek a simple script/batch file to close a program at a certain time. Someone recently gave me a single line of text that I put into a notepad and had Task Manager run this file at a certain time and that worked. But I had to format that hard drive and lost the file.

So my goal is to run a batch file that will kill a process at a set time each day. Let's call the program flubber.exe. I'm not a programmer and the research I've done on tskill has only confused me. I know it was a simple short command but I am unable to remember it. Help.....
Thank you to all who respond.

Majikwiz

Answer (score 0):

```
taskkill /im flubber.exe /t
```

This will terminate all running processes with executable name `flubber.exe`.